# Stop current animation and re-play immediately?

Tags: animation, godot

When the player hit something, I'm playing hit animation from animation_player. However when player hit something while hit animation is playing, it just ignored and play previous hit animation.

I need to stop the animation, but couldn't find any related information. How do I stop the animation and play again immediately?

Answer (score 1):

> it just ignored and play previous hit animation

I'm assuming you mean that the animation continues playing from its current position rather than resetting to the beginning.

> How do I stop the animation and play again immediately?

By stopping it and playing it again:

```
animation_player.stop()
animation_player.play("my_animation")
```

The [docs on `stop`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_animationplayer.html#class-animationplayer-method-stop) say:

> Stops the currently playing animation. If reset is true, the animation position is reset to 0 and the playback speed is reset to 1.0.
>   If reset is false, then calling play without arguments or play("same_as_before") will resume the animation.

As `reset` defaults to `false`, calling `stop()` is sufficient.